# How to validate data from csv file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

My CSV file contains 3 columns: first name,last name,email. I want to add all the valid lines of the CSV file in the users table in the database. For example: if the CSV file has 10 lines where line 2 is missing first name and line 3 has invalid email, I want to see 8 users added to database. After adding the users from the CSV file, it should display how many users were added and how many failed.

My model:

```
 const User = sequelize.define(
    "users",
    {
      first_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      last_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(60),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false,
      },
```

My Controller:

```
 const upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if (req.file == undefined) {
        return res.status(400).send("Please upload a CSV file!");
      }
     
      let users = [];
      console.log(" __basedir",  __basedir);
      let path = __basedir + "/uploads/" + req.file.filename;

  
      fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
        .on("error", (error) => {
          throw error.message;
        })
        .on("data", (row) => {
          users.push(row);
        })
        .on("end", () => {
          User.bulkCreate(users, {
            validate: true,
          })
            .then(() => {
              res.status(200).send({
                message:
                  `Uploaded ${users.length} data  successfully from ` + req.file.originalname,
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              res.status(500).send({
                message: `Fail to import ${users.length}  into database!`,
                error: error.message,
              });
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Could not upload the file: " + req.file.originalname,
      });
    }
};
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using fast-csv package

```
import * as csv from 'fast-csv';

const upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      if (req.file == undefined) {
        return res.status(400).send("Please upload a CSV file!");
      }
     
      let users = [];
      console.log(" __basedir",  __basedir);
      let path = __basedir + "/uploads/" + req.file.filename;

      console.log("path", path);


  let emailPattern= /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
  let successCount = 0;
  let errorCount = 0;
      fs.createReadStream(path)
        .pipe(csv.parse({  headers: [ undefined,'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', undefined ],renameHeaders: true, ignoreEmpty: true }))
        .validate(data => data.first_name !== '' && data.last_name !== '' && emailPattern.test(data.email))
        .on("error", (error) => {          
          throw error.message;
        })
        .on("data", (row) => {
          successCount++;
          users.push(row);
          console.log(`ROW=${JSON.stringify(row)}`)
        })
        .on('data-invalid', (row, rowNumber) => {
          errorCount++;
          console.log(`Invalid [rowNumber=${rowNumber}] [row=${JSON.stringify(row)}]`)
        })
        .on("end", (rowCount) => {
          console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`)
          User.bulkCreate(users, {
            validate: true,
          })
           
          
            .then(async() => {
           
              res.status(200).json({
                error: false,
                success:
                  `Uploaded ${successCount} row successfully from ` + req.file.originalname,
                failed:`Uploaded ${errorCount} row failed from ` + req.file.originalname,
                     
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              res.status(500).json({
                error: error.message,
                failed: `Fail to import ${users.length} row into database!`,
            
              });
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: error.message,
        failed: "Could not upload the file: " + req.file.originalname,
      });
    }
};
```